# Buscar dentro de un fichero mediante grep

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

En un .txt hay varios DNI, lo que quiero hacer es mediante el comando grep filtrar para que me saque los DNI que tengan 9 numeros y 1 letra. Lo he intentado mediante este comando pero no me sirve:

INTERIOR DEL FICHERO:

```
123456789A

31232g

42344324f

324f

4554345345345g

234452l
```

INSTRUCCION QUE HE UTILIZADO:

```
cat nif.txt|grep -E "[[:digit:]]{9}[[:alpha:]]{1}"

123456789A

4554345345345g
```

Me saca un DNI erroneo y eso es lo que no quiero que haga. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que si cuentas desde el principio esos 9 caracteres más la letra y también especificas que luego tampoco debe haber más caracteres lo conseguirás.

Para ello usa el símbolo `^` que indica que la coincidencia a buscar debe empezar la línea, y al final le pones un símbolo `$` que indique que después del patrón a buscar no debe haber nada más (indica final de línea):

```
cat nif.txt|grep -E "^[[:digit:]]{9}[[:alpha:]]{1}$"
```

porque del otro modo, tal como lo tenias, le daba igual si antes salian más caracteres **antes** de encontrarlo o bien **después** (por ejemplo, esto también lo encontraba: **423443246fXXX**`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de gran ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro por tí :-)  Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta recuerda que puedes aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas.  También te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para aprender la dinámica del funcionamiento de este sitio (son 3 minutos de tutorial) y así obtendrás una nueva medalla!